# Facet Sorting in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to mention the order of sorting in SOLR facets.

I'm using `f.<fieldname>.facet.sort=count` which is always sorting in descending order (highest count first)

Eg:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="myfield">
<int name="a">97</int>
<int name="b">44</int>
<int name="c">42</int>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Is there any way to sort in ascending order.

Eg:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="myfield">
<int name="c">42</int>
<int name="b">44</int>
<int name="a">97</int>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Any information will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unresolved issue ([SOLR-1672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1672)) for the same problem in the Jira. They added a patch, maybe it will help you.